# Notify when puppet wants to change something

Tags: puppet

I am currently working on implementing puppet in our environment, however, I have a request I dont know if puppet itself can fill.

If I have a configuration under /etc/myconfig.conf. And I want it to be written only if it doesnt already exist; I can use the onlyif function. But is there any way that I can get puppet to do something, a notify() or something if it detect a change in a file..?

I dont want it to actually change the file, only notify me that the file is not the way it want it to be..

There is really no examples or anything in this question, but I hope someone is able to push me in the right direction here. If I create a solution for this based on tips, I will post the answer myself for others to learn from.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For only creating a file if it doesn't exist, try setting replace to false, like so:

```
file { "/etc/myconfig.conf":
  ensure => present,
  source => "puppet:///modules/${module_name}/myconfig.conf",
  replace => false,
}
```

Docs for that are here: http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/2.7.0/type.html#file

For the notification, puppet auditing will do what you need:
http://puppetlabs.com/blog/all-about-auditing-with-puppet/

Comment: Audit looks like the right way to do this. I didnt find audit in the documentation, but thanks for pointing that one out :)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want puppet to alert you of any changes it WOULD do rather than do them.

For this, just run with noop (--noop)

it will tell you every change it is going to do but not perform them.

Comment: You may not want to run it manually on 100+ nodes. So you get a notification email telling you what _would_ be changed.